# MongoDb .NET Mapping Inherited Class Members

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have an issue where I am unable to map (string Id property) in base class for the Derived class, as mongodb only maps properties within the class it self not including the inherited properties, unless I move the property from base to derived I couldnt find away to map it, please note that base class will serve many other derived classes, and I am trying to use BsonClassMap instead of atrributes, is there away to map that property and include it in derived class mapping?